# Assembly's definition does not match

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-assembly

> Error 2   Could not load file or assembly
>   'CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework, Version=10.2.3600.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Can anyone tell how to correct this error?
I tried to delete the files from the bin folder and I even tried downloading a new dll file and added reference to it. Still it didnt work out.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was pretty simple. Just delete the assembly and associated files from my projects bin folder and then choose Add Reference to add the latest version back in.

Comment: plus 1 : This Worked For Me, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to your project file referring to one version while the version copied into the bin folder is a different one.  So when the app runs it's trying to load the version the project file references, but finds only the one copied into the bin folder.

Was the library added through Nuget?  It could be that the version in the referenced in packages.config and used in the build doesn't match the version number in the project file.

Comment: yes, the library was added through Nuget and the dll file which I downloaded didnt state the version so I assumed it to be 13.0.2000.0 but it didnt work for it so I changed it to 10.2.3600.0 but it didnt work still. I have deleted the version in the bin folder and I have added the reference to the new dll file. So I guess it wont be finding the one copied in the bin folder of the project? or would it?

Comment: The packages.config tells you what the versions of installed packages are.  The list of References in the project should tell you which version the project expects.  For the actual files, check the file properties of the DLL.  If you search for all instances of  the DLL you should be able to locate the one with the incorrect version and remove it.  You may end up having to remove and add the Nuget package again to make sure the projects are using the correct versions.  I've had occasions where that also required deleting the relevant folders in the package folder.